# How to remove text-decoration: underline from pseudoelement?

Tags: css

I have `text-decoration: underline` on `a` and I would need to keep it like that. But I am also trying to remove the underline from the pseudoelement, overriding it with `text-decoration: none !important;` seems to have no effect. Can something be done about it?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMzJoZ

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:before {
  content: '#';
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">asdf</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pseudoelement is just an inline text node, which can't really be modified too easily without changing it's display type. Add `display: inline-block;` - this should allow you to manipulate it independently.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a::before {
  content: '#';
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">asdf</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```